# Why can't I create a Google DataProc cluster with both Jupyter and DataLab installed?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-datalab

I want to create a cluster in DataProc with both Jupyter and DataLab installed (I understand they are very similar but team members have different preference). I can create cluster with any of them:

Cluster with Jupyter:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create $DATAPROC_CLUSTER_NAME_JUPYTER \
--project $PROJECT \
--bucket $BUCKET \
--zone $ZONE \
--initialization-actions gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/connectors/connectors.sh,gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/jupyter.sh \
--metadata gcs-connector-version=$GCS_CONNECTOR_VERSION \
--metadata bigquery-connector-version=$BQ_CONNECTOR_VERSION \
--metadata JUPYTER_PORT=$JUPYTER_PORT,JUPYTER_CONDA_PACKAGES=numpy:scipy:pandas:scikit-learn
```

Cluster with DataLab:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create $DATAPROC_CLUSTER_NAME_DATALAB \
--project $PROJECT \
--bucket $BUCKET \
--zone $ZONE \
--master-boot-disk-size $MASTER_DISK_SIZE \
--worker-boot-disk-size $WORKER_DISK_SIZE \
--initialization-actions gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/connectors/connectors.sh,gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/datalab/datalab.sh \
--metadata gcs-connector-version=$GCS_CONNECTOR_VERSION \
--metadata bigquery-connector-version=$BQ_CONNECTOR_VERSION \
--scopes cloud-platform,bigquery
```

And both work well. However, when I try to create a cluster with both of them, it fails:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create test \
--project $PROJECT \
--bucket $BUCKET \
--zone $ZONE \
--initialization-actions gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/connectors/connectors.sh,gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/datalab/datalab.sh,gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/jupyter.sh \
--metadata gcs-connector-version=$GCS_CONNECTOR_VERSION \
--metadata bigquery-connector-version=$BQ_CONNECTOR_VERSION \
--metadata JUPYTER_PORT=$JUPYTER_PORT,JUPYTER_CONDA_PACKAGES=numpy:scipy:pandas:scikit-learn \
--scopes cloud-platform,bigquery
```

The error message are:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.clusters.create) Operation [projects/abc/regions/global/operations/d34943dc-5bda-386f-af91-db6e0516e2c5] failed: Multiple Errors:
 - Initialization action failed. Failed action 'gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/jupyter.sh', see output in: gs://abc/google-cloud-dataproc-metainfo/266175ef-e595-4732-b351-335837a3f30e/test-m/dataproc-initialization-script-2_output
 - Initialization action failed. Failed action 'gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/jupyter.sh', see output in: gs://abc/google-cloud-dataproc-metainfo/266175ef-e595-4732-b351-335837a3f30e/test-w-0/dataproc-initialization-script-2_output
 - Initialization action failed. Failed action 'gs://dataproc-initialization-actions/jupyter/jupyter.sh', see output in: gs://abc/google-cloud-dataproc-metainfo/266175ef-e595-4732-b351-335837a3f30e/test-w-1/dataproc-initialization-script-2_output.
```

The file in test-m looks like following:

```
++ /usr/share/google/get_metadata_value attributes/dataproc-role
+ readonly ROLE=Worker
+ ROLE=Worker
++ /usr/share/google/get_metadata_value attributes/INIT_ACTIONS_REPO
++ echo https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions.git
+ readonly INIT_ACTIONS_REPO=https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions.git
+ INIT_ACTIONS_REPO=https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions.git
++ /usr/share/google/get_metadata_value attributes/INIT_ACTIONS_BRANCH
++ echo master
+ readonly INIT_ACTIONS_BRANCH=master
+ INIT_ACTIONS_BRANCH=master
++ /usr/share/google/get_metadata_value attributes/JUPYTER_CONDA_CHANNELS
+ readonly JUPYTER_CONDA_CHANNELS=
+ JUPYTER_CONDA_CHANNELS=
++ /usr/share/google/get_metadata_value attributes/JUPYTER_CONDA_PACKAGES
+ readonly JUPYTER_CONDA_PACKAGES=numpy:scipy:pandas:scikit-learn
+ JUPYTER_CONDA_PACKAGES=numpy:scipy:pandas:scikit-learn
+ echo 'Cloning fresh dataproc-initialization-actions from repo https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions.git and branch master...'
Cloning fresh dataproc-initialization-actions from repo https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions.git and branch master...
+ git clone -b master --single-branch https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataproc-initialization-actions.git
fatal: destination path 'dataproc-initialization-actions' already exists and is not an empty directory.
```

Looks like there is a clone step which prevents the installation from success. How can I solve this? Any suggestion is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in the init actions where we can't `git clone` the repository twice. We will fix this.

In the mean time, you can try [Jupyter optional component](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/components/jupyter) instead with datalab init action.

Comment: Thank you. However, when I added `--optional-components=JUPYTER \
--image-version=1.3 \` to the second line, it gives me the error: ERROR: (gcloud.dataproc.clusters.create) unrecognized arguments: --optional-components=JUPYTER. I have been having issues with --optional-components all the time. (My image version is debian 1.3.) How can I deal with it?

Comment: Looks like you may have to update your gcloud to at least version [238.0.0](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/release-notes#23800_2019-03-12) via `gcloud components update`

Comment: If you use `gcloud beta dataproc` then you can use Jupyter component with [Component Gateway](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/accessing/dataproc-gateways) and get access to Jupyter UI without SSH tunnels.

Comment: I tried the gcloud beta dataproc commands, and it can create a cluster successfully. However, when I use gcloud beta dataproc clusters describe cluster-name and copy the url of Jupyter or JupyterLab, it can't be accessed in Chrome (Error 504 all the time). How can I solve this?

Comment: Would you mind reaching out to dataproc-feedback [at] google.com with your clusters region, cluster name, and projectId so we can have a closer look?